# C# list adding instead of replacing

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to lists but I want to use it to write in a File with it.
So as an example how I'm using it at the moment (not exactly like this) I've created some code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentString = Convert.ToString(Line);
    List<string> ContentList = new List<string>();
    ContentList.Add(ContentString);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"Test.txt",ContentList);
    Line = Line + 1;
}
```

(I've declared `Line` (int) and `ContentString` (string) as global variables)

My problem now is that I'm just getting a file where in the first line there is a number which counts up. But I want multiple Lines from 1 to X.
I wanted to use `ContentList.Add(ContentString[Line]);` but that just works with an Array.

So how do I add a string into a new Line of a List?

Comment: Its not clear what you are actually trying to do. DO you want multiple copies of ContentString written to the file?

Comment: You create a new collection and only add one thing to it every time you click the button.  The list would have to be declared at a scope outside the button click event.

Comment: " I wanted to use "ContentList.Add(ContentString[Line]);" but that just works with an Array." What does that mean? `Add` only works with a List, which is what you have. ContentString is a string, you cannot do [Line] on it .

Comment: LarsTech you are right, I'm just a bit stupid. Didn't think about that, thank you a lot, It's working now.^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you overwrite the file with the list each time you click the button. And the list only contains the latest number.

Either create a list once and add numbers to it, or skip all that complicated stuff and do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"Test.txt", Line.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    Line = Line + 1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right I'm just dumb and didn't think about that. Thanks a lot.^^ I've declared it global now so It's working.

Answer (score 5):

You create a new `List<string>` every time the button is clicked, and just add the latest `Line` value to it before writing it.

To have all the previous items written, you need to create the `List<string>` once and add to it each time

```
private List<string> ContentList = new List<string>();
private int Line = 1;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentString = Convert.ToString(Line);       
    ContentList.Add(ContentString);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"Test.txt",ContentList);
    Line = Line + 1;

}
```

Note: The above demonstrates the way to fix your existing code, not necessarily the right way to write this functionality